# How to add GCP IAM roles to Service Account

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-swarm, docker-machine, google-iam

I am trying to create a docker swarm node on a VM instance on GCP using `docker-machine`.

```
docker-machine create swarm-node -d google --google-machine-type e2-standard-2 --google-zone europe-north1-a --google-project myproject-name
```

I use a GCP Service Account in localhost docker-machine CLI.

`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/my-name-here/.gcp/path-to-my-service-account-keyfile.json"`

But I got this error:

```
Error with pre-create check: "Project with ID \"myproject-name\" not found. googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.projects.get' permission for 'projects/myproject-name', forbidden"
```

How can I add `compute.projects.get` GCP IAM access to the GCP Service Account?

Answer (score 16):

Finally I figured out, as explained at:
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access

1. In the Cloud Console, go to the IAM page
2. Click Add.
3. Enter the service-account email address (displayed in service-account dashboard).
4. Select a role, in this case `Compute Admin`
5. Click Save.

Et voilà

Comment: This is so intuitive I can't believe I spent close to an hour trying to figure it out